# Find all references to an object in Lua

Tags: debugging, memory-leaks, lua

I have a memory leak in the Lua part of my application. For whatever reason, my object is not getting deleted when it should (even when I call `collectgarbage("collect")`). I assume this means I have a dangling reference somewhere.

So how may I obtain a list of where various references to an object reside? For example:

```
obj = MyObject()
ref = obj
tbl = {obj}
obj = nil
print(getreferences(obj)) -- should print something like _G.ref, _G.tbl[1]
```

I would simply write my own function for this, but it would not be able to find references contained inside of closures. Any advice?

Comment: Lua tables and objects don't have names. Therefore, all you would get is a list of table addresses, which would not be very helpful.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: That's not completely true. If I were to start at the toplevel, _G and use pairs(_G) to work my way down until I found a key whose value matched what I am searching for, I would be supplied with the full path to the reference. I just don't know how to access the values residing within closures from outside the closure.

Comment: And what if the table is a _key_? That's entirely legal Lua code. What if the key to the table isn't a string? What if it isn't in the global table _at all_, which is also entirely possible. It could be in the registry, or it could be in a function's local environment. Lua does not require all objects to be reachable from `_G`.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Well I can tell you that in this application, I only used strings and integers as keys. Seeing as how it is pure lua, I don't think it's in the registry (though I'm not too familiar with Lua). And so the only problem I see is with a function's local variables. But the debug tracebacks are able to provide information about that, so surely there must be a way for me to obtain that info as well?

Comment: My point is that _Lua_ cannot assume that your tables are only in the global table indexed by integers and strings. Therefore, if Lua were to have a facility where it tracked down all references to tables, it would not be able to _name_ any of those tables, because tables do not have names. Which is why Lua does not have the ability to do so.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Lua is garbage collected.  So at some level there has to be a root object (or a list of root objects).  Everything not reachable via the root object is collected.  You've pointed out that `_G` is cannot be that root object.  The question is still good however. _"What is the reachability path the GC found that is stopping my object from being collected?"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a tool to traverse the whole Lua universe. See http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-07/msg00110.html

Comment: See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531901/is-my-lua-object-being-collected.  I believe this script will not find all references to an object.  At least, it did not do so for me.  Use it with caution.