# Is my Lua object being collected?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, lua

**The warning:**

I am now convinced that the problem is that the luatraverse script [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166124/find-all-references-to-an-object-in-lua) just does not work as advertised, and does not find all the references to an object.  In my example, I found where the object was being referenced, thus preventing its collection, but that was not reported by the script.

Therefore, the basic premise of this question is somewhat flawed.

**The backgound:**

I am working on enhancing the scripting engine in the game [Bitfighter](http://bitfighter.org).  I am not convinced that memory is being released properly.  So I constructed a test, in the form of the script below.

It prints 3 columns of userdatas.  Column 1 is a userdata I expect to be used nowhere else, and should therefore be destroyed by the collectgarbage function.  Columns 2 and 3 are objects I do not believe should be collected, because I am keeping a handle on them.

**The problem:**

The userdata in column 1 never varies, so I suspect it is not being collected (cols. 2 and 3 behave as expected).  To further clarify the situation, I am using the luatraverse script mentioned in [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166124/find-all-references-to-an-object-in-lua), which seems to confirm that there is only one reference to obj100, which is that stored in obj100 itself.  I tried adding an assignment just before running countreferences (local x = obj100), and, as expected, countreferences reported the object being referenced twice.

**The questions:**

1) Am I interpreting this output correctly, and is obj100 really never collected?  Or is it possible that the same memory addresses is being reused over and over?

2) Is there a better way than the luatraverse script to see what is referencing a particular Lua object?

**The code:**

```
 -- Every 2 seconds, find two objects with ids 100 and 200, and print their addrs
 -- No reference is kept for object 100, so its userdata might change over time
 -- Object 200 is held by objHolder, so its userdata should remain constant

 -- Obj200 should remain constant over time; obj100 can vary.  
 -- objHolder should be constant, obviously

 local ltraverse = require("luatraverse")


 function printIds()
    local obj100 = levelgen:findObjectById(100)
    local obj200 = levelgen:findObjectById(200)
    print("Obj 100:" .. tostring(obj100) .. " Obj 200:" .. 
           tostring(obj200) .. " Held:" .. tostring(objHolder))


    print(ltraverse.countreferences(obj100))

    obj100 = nil
    obj200 = nil

    collectgarbage()
 end

 function main()
    -- levelgen:findObjectById is a local game command that
    -- creates a userdata for an object
    local obj100 = levelgen:findObjectById(100)
    objHolder    = levelgen:findObjectById(200)     -- not local, global

    assert(obj100)
    assert(objHolder)

    print("Column 1 can vary; 2 and 3 should be constant")
    print("=============================================")

    print("Obj 100:" .. tostring(obj100) .. " Obj 200:" .. 
         tostring(objHolder) .. " Held:" .. tostring(objHolder))

    obj100 = nil

    -- Run a function every 2 seconds
    Timer:scheduleRepeating(printIds, 2000)
 end
```

**The output:**

```
 Column 1 can vary; 2 and 3 should be constant
 =============================================
 Obj 100:userdata: 02FC9700 Obj 200:userdata: 02FAD280 Held:userdata: 02FAD280

 Obj 100:userdata: 02FC9700 Obj 200:userdata: 02FAD280 Held:userdata: 02FAD280
 1
 Obj 100:userdata: 02FC9700 Obj 200:userdata: 02FAD280 Held:userdata: 02FAD280
 1
 Obj 100:userdata: 02FC9700 Obj 200:userdata: 02FAD280 Held:userdata: 02FAD280
 1
 Obj 100:userdata: 02FC9700 Obj 200:userdata: 02FAD280 Held:userdata: 02FAD280
 1
 Obj 100:userdata: 02FC9700 Obj 200:userdata: 02FAD280 Held:userdata: 02FAD280
 1
 ... and onward to infinity ...
```

Comment: Have you considered actually tracking the memory usage by Lua instead of this more convoluted test? Lua lets you install a allocation/deallocation function, so just use that to track when memory is allocated and deleted in Lua.

Comment: I am now convinced that the object is not collected (see my final comment below); the question is why not?  My real goal is to determine what is holding on to a reference and thus preventing collection.  I am surprised to see only 1 reference to my object (a local var set to nil before I manually collect the garbage), because that supports my belief that there are no lingering references, but contradicts my observation that the object is not being collected.  Tracking the memory would help confirm the lack of collection, but not tell me why. Clearly I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Bitfighter, but I assume you're measuring wrong things here:

This line will create a new Lua userdata object essentially pointing to the real C++(?) object:

```
local obj100 = levelgen:findObjectById(100)
```

Later on the following line will print the number of references withing Lua pointing to that userdata (`obj100`, not the actual data):

```
print(ltraverse.countreferences(obj100))
```

This will always be 1, because you just created that object with one reference to it.

The reference/Lua object is most likely collected, you won't see that. The actual userdata (pointer) is always the same, because you're requesting the same object ID. Therefore this value must not change, unless the associated data is moved/reallocated by some other code.

But in the end, I'd say this really depends on what `levelgen:findObjectById()` returns. What happens if you try the following lines?

```
local temp
local obj100 = temp = levelgen:findObjectById(100)
```

Comment: Is it possible I am just misunderstanding what the userdata tostring method prints?  I assume it is the address of the userdata itself, but I can't find any documentation to confirm that.  If it is in fact the address of the object it is wrapping, then that might explain the situation.

Comment: It really depends on the actual kind of userdata, because Lua knows "light userdata" as well as "heavy userdata". Light userdata isn't more than just a pointer value pointing to memory handled by the outside world. Heavy userdata is some allocated memory handled (and GC'ed) by Lua. However, I'm not sure whether there'd be some difference in what's printed if you try to print both.

Comment: This is heavy userdata.  If I make the code changes you suggested, I get essentially the same thing, but with a 2 printed every second line, which is exactly what I'd expect.  Doing some testing suggests that the address that is printed is not that of the underlying object.

Comment: It's just reused then. With my change there are 2 references (`temp` and `obj100`) pointing at the temporary object. Do `obj100 = nil` right before counting and you should get 0.

Comment: I don't think the object is being gc'ed.  It turns out there is a __gc method on the metatable, and that is not called until the lua_State is shut down.  That suggests to me that something is preventing the objects from being collected.  I should mention that there is a userdata cache (using a weak table) that explains why I would get the same userdata back for obj100 if it weren't collected; it does not explain why it is not collected when the reference count can be explained solely by local variables. The only thing I can think of is that countreferences misses some reference somewhere.

Comment: If there's a `__gc` method it won't be collected. The C/C++ code has to trigger it (lookup documentation).

Comment: Are you sure this is right?  I believe the __gc method is just a block of code that gets called when the method is gc'ed.  From the manual: "When a userdatum is about to be collected and its metatable has a __gc field, Lua calls the value of this field (which should be a function), passing as an argument the userdatum itself. This function can then release any resource associated with that userdatum."

Comment: Yeah you're right, might have had something different in mind.